# Reduce the size of the code for some checker

Tags: c#, text-files

I have 2 functions, the first cleans the file from the empty tapes and the second removes the duplicates, I would like to merge them

```
File.WriteAllLines(@".\temporal.txt",File.ReadAllLines(@".\temporal.txt").Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)));

File.WriteAllLines(@".\temporal.txt",File.ReadAllLines(@".\temporal.txt").Distinct().ToArray());
```

Comment: You can use File.WriteAllLines(@".\temporal.txt",File.ReadAllLines(@".\temporal.txt").Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l).Distinct().ToArray())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading and writing file twice you can read it once and do all operations, then Write it into file

Like,

```
var fileData = File.ReadAllLines(@".\temporal.txt")
                   .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToArray();

File.WriteAllLines(@".\temporal.txt", fileData);
```